# getting error while running boruta

Tags: r

I was trying to do variable reduction by using boruta..

I ran the code

```
boruta.train <-Boruta(flag~.-Proposalno,data=trainingdtabkt1nrml,doTrace=2)
```

where flag is my objective/dependent variable. After 65 iterations I am getting the following error

> 65. run of importance source... Computing permutation importance.. Progress: 30%. Estimated remaining time: 1 minute, 10 seconds.
>       Computing permutation importance.. Progress: 64%. Estimated remaining
>       time: 34 seconds. Computing permutation importance.. Progress: 95%.
>       Estimated remaining time: 4 seconds. Rejected 1 attributes:
>       df1_On.Book.
>
>     66. run of importance source... Error: std::bad_alloc Ranger will EXIT now. Error in ranger::ranger(data = x, dependent.variable.name =
>           "shadow.Boruta.decision",  :    User interrupt or internal error.

Any idea why this error is happening or how to fix it ..never got it earlier..

Comment: Add the data to make this reproducible.

Comment: This says the user interrupted it.